# How to make Eslint/Prettier fail on errors and warnings inside ci environment?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, eslint, prettier

I have a Vue app using Eslint with Prettier. A Github action should check the code style, but `npm run lint -- --no-fix` only logs the warnings, the workflow doesn't fail.

My test PR:

[image]

The workflow passes although I would expect it to fail. Is there a flag for this? E.g.

```
npm run lint -- --no-fix --fail-on-errors-and-warnings
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--max-warnings=0` this should do the trick.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised this isn't an option for the .eslintrc file

Comment: for reference, this is the help text in eslint 8.31.0: `--max-warnings Int              Number of warnings to trigger nonzero exit code - default: -1`